# Launch an activity from a menu button?

Tags: java, android, menu, android-activity

I've making an app and I want to launch a new activity from a menu, but ever time I click the menu button, the app crashes. I've tried many ways and all of the have failed.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
new MenuInflater(getApplication())
        .inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);


return(super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu));
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.Menu1:          
    Toast.makeText(this, "Coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
   case R.id.Menu2:
       Intent Intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
       startActivity(Intent);


 }
return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
}
```

Android Manifest

> ```
>     <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
>   <activity android:name=".AndroidRssReader"
>             android:label="@string/app_name">
>       <intent-filter>
>           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>       </intent-filter>
>   </activity>
>   <activity android:name=".About" android:label="@string/app_label"></activity>
> ```

Comment: is about declared as activity in your manifest file?

Comment: Without log / stack trace we cant help much...

Comment: I ran it again with some code from an answer below, and now it is highlighting `switch (item,getIemId()) {`

Comment: that should be a dot `.` not a comma.  If it still doesn't work after fixing that, please post the stacktrace from your logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My implementation of `onOptionsItemSelected()` is slightly different as I am returning `true` when I have handled the selection myself, rather than always passing to the superclass.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Menu1:
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,About.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29)

We really need to see the logcat to be sure though

Comment: I use the exact same code and it works perfectly! However I just wondered, the doc is not very clear about when to call the base class... should we be calling it in all cases instead?

Comment: @Gromix I was going by the wording of the documentation: `boolean Return false to allow normal menu processing to proceed, true to consume it here.`  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the docs?

Comment: this goes along with my quick answer of finishing the switch statement correctly.

Comment: What confuses me is `Derived classes should call through to the base class for it to perform the default menu handling`. It's not clear whether the default menu handling should always be executed or not, for example for cleanup or to maintain some sort of state. Not that I saw any obvious difference not calling it....

Comment: @Gromix I was assuming that the code in my `case` statement is the handling that I want to perform for that menu item, which would mean that I wouldn't want the default handling to execute.  I agree with you that the wording is ambiguous, and either interpretation could be correct.

Answer (score 7):

```
Intent Intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
startActivity(Intent);
```

This needs to become

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @dave.c - 5 other people seem to think it does.  Would you please explain why?

Comment: @user: it's just a proper naming convention that probably should be followed, but the compiler doesn't really care about lower/upper case or how the variables are named (as long as you don't use reserved words).

Answer (score 1):

It could be a few things, for example is the **About** class in your root package? (since you declare it as `android:name=".About"`)

But the best way to troubleshoot this is to have a look at the crash details in **Logcat** (both Eclipse and IntelliJ have a Logcat plugin). What does it say?

Answer (score 1):

I just did the same thing, ie, launch an activity from a menu button; and it worked fine. As for the resolving of the variable with the same name as the class, i'm not so sure of. The declaration may work fine, but further references to that variable won't be accurate is my guess. Also, make sure all control paths in the onOptionsItemSelected function return a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a class into your startActivity method, not an Intent. You're declaring Intent Intent. You need to do `Intent intent`, or `Intent myIntent`, something like that. You can't have the same name for a variable as it's class, just as you can't do `int int`.

Comment: That would indeed be so much better for legibility, but Java is smart enough to realise it's just a variable name starting with upper case.

Comment: Really? I actually didn't know that, that's pretty cool. You'd think encouraging that would be a bad idea; a compiler warning would discourage that kind of behavior.

Comment: Agreed! I think a static code analysis tool like Checkstyle would probably complain.

Answer (score 0):

Android may be having difficulty starting your `About` class, e.g. an exception is being thrown in `onCreate()`. Looking at the stack trace in `logcat` may confirm this. Post the stack trace if its unclear to what is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation but your switch statement should break and have a default case. it will help prevent errors in the future and possibly help with this issue. Other than that, post logs...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this fix the problem. I paste a example part below. Because, I think you forgot to made a new/second activity in your AndroidManifest.

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    <activity
        android:name="YourPackageName.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    **<activity 
       android:name="YourPackageName.SecondActivity" />   

    <activity 
       android:name="YourPackageName.ThirdActivity" />**   

</application>
```

I hope this is gonna help you!

ADDED Post:

And this is my code, must be work! Put it in your main or something else, but not in the activity from your button.

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.MenuButton_About:
        Toast.makeText(this, "YourPopupText.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent("Name of this activity".this, "Name of the menu button acivity".class));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

You can also use: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT -> Toast.LENGTH_LONG

I hope this is gonna help you!

Answer (score 0):

Check your About java activity file. I had a similar problem where the project would compile OK but the app would force a shutdown when the menu button was selected. When I rewrote the second activity everything was fine!